# Problemas con las rutas CSS para aplicar fuentes en servidor Real

Tags: css

llevo unos días peleándome con el añadir unas fuentes muy especificas para una página web, En el servidor local me aparece correcto todo, la web está bien pero a la hora de subir lo me de un error

**En Firefox es este**

```
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Florentia-med" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0) source: https://www.<mi_web>.com/fonts/Florentia-medium-trial.ttf
```

**En Chrome es el siguente**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

No entiendo el por qué la verdad ya que el css tengo rutas parecidas que lo único que cambia es la carpeta.

**El CSS de las fuentes es el siguiente**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Florentia";
    src: url("../fonts/Florentia-thin-trial.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Florentia-bold";
    src: url("../fonts/Florentia-bold-trial.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Florentia-med";
    src: url("../fonts/Florentia-medium-trial.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Helveticaneue";
    src: url("../fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttc");
}
/*aqui aplico la fuente al body y yso las demás para otros fines*/
body {
    background-color:rgb(152,209,201);
    font-family: Florentia-med ,sans-serif ;
}
```

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, claramente el problema está en donde estás guardando el archivo, no en su contenido. Chrome te dice que hay algo que no ha encontrado, pero no te dice el qué, igual necesitas sacar los Chrome developer tools (F12 creo) para ver qué te falta.
Firefox te dice que el problema está en la fuente, hay algún problema cuando enlazas a buscarla y descargarla.

Aquí tienes un problema similar resuelto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429519/font-awesome-error-downloadable-font-rejected-by-sanitizer

Supongo que  es el nombre de la web omitido, revisa qué tienes ahí en ese directorio, paso a paso, ve quitando partes del path a ver hasta dónde puedes leer.

Comment: No tengo ni idea de lo que pasa y el link que me has pasado no me ayuda a mucho, si es problemas del servidor poco puedo hacer, y ecuanto a Google, es extraño ya que si es problema de la ruta, deberia pasar los mismo con las imagenes que pongo mediante css en las url lo unico que cambia es el nombre de carpeta :(

Comment: puedes abrir la carpeta desde el exterior? puedes acceder a ella? si colocas una imagen en esa carpeta la descarga?

Comment: en local puedo aceder a ella a lo que me refiero es que las url son  **imagenes* `url(../imagenes/mi-imagen.jpg)` para fuentes es `url(../fonts/mifuente.ttf)` lo curioso es que las fuentes que son **.woff .otf ** y demás no da errores, entocne sno entiendo lo que pasa la verdad

Comment: haz una cosa, como te he dicho, mete una imagen en ../imagenes/miimagen.jpg e intenta descargarla desde la web, y mira a ver si se ve, pero no en local, sino en el servidor remoto y me cuentas qué te da.

Comment: 1.- no ves la imagen: tienes un problema con el directorio: probablemente permisos. 2.- ves la imagen, entonces el problema es el archivo de la fuente, mira permisos del servidor, cortafuegos, etc...

Comment: YA he descargado las imagenes las que tinen etiqueta `HTML` incluso cuando busco la imagen en `CSS` la encuentro y la descargo va todo bien :( estoy agobiado

Comment: las hs descargado desde el directorio que te da problemas? supongamos que si, entonces el problema está en los permisos de las fuentes. tienes problemas en todas o solo en una? porque solo das un error

Comment: tengo mas fuentes, pero justo las de **florentia.ttf** dante error tengo otras con esa misma extension y van bien, por una parte firefox da el error aquel  `downloadable ` y chrome de el `Failed to decode downloaded font` pero vuelvo y repito solo es en ese tipo de fuente

Comment: veo que es un trial, has mirado las condiciones?

Comment: que condiciones?, sorry por la pregunta pero aun soy algo novato en cuento a css se refiere

Comment: si es lo que yo creo, tuve un problema similar pero se manifestaba de forma distinta. Tu fuente es de pago, no es gratis, lo que tienes es una versión de prueba, habrá ciertas condiciones que no se cumplan y por ello hay problemas: tal como el periodo de prueba ha expirado, uso equivocado, etc... https://www.dafont.com/florentia.font

Comment: pues puede ser una posibilidad, me acaba de explotar el cerebro ahora mismo jaja y ahora que hago? estas fuentes me las pasaron unos diseñadores, aunque la cosas es que en local ´<mi ip>/mi_pagina´ si funciona entocnes ahi es donde mi cerebro sigue micro explotando jaja

Comment: escribe a los de la fuente de soporte tecnico, si es para una empresa privada, igual hay alguna condicion que las puedes usar solo localmente, pero escribe a preguntar cuales son las condiciones de uso, a los diseñadores o a los desarrolladores de la propia fuente. Lo que sí puedes hacer es poner una fuente alternativa si hay problemas con esa

Comment: el tema está que es el clinete es algo caprichoso debido a que quiere el mismo tipo de letra que va con el logo asi que voy a ver que soluciones, hablaré con los diseñadores graficos uqe me proporcionaron las fuentes a ver que me dicen, muchas gracias